# Position Relative in nested list for Family Tree

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a family tree with multiple parent option. I have looked around and I havent found anything with this aspect.

Starting from http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree I have modified it a little bit to get this:
http://www.gmrv.es/~sschvartzman/Sara_C._Schvartzman/prueba.html

The marriage link is simply another element of the list of parents, but with 0 height. My problem now is that I cant get the children to be centered w.r.t. the marriage. That is, in the example, the children of the second marriage are set to the right of the family. Only child 2.1 and 2.2 are centered in the second marriage.

Why is this happening if I have all the elements of the children list set to position:relative?

Here is the html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link href="tree.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Family Tree</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tree">
  <ul class="pf">
    <li class="parent"><a href="" class="m">
      <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:central; padding:30px 10px; width:80px;">Husband<br>1<span>(1861 - 1894)</span></div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="marriage">
          <ul class="c">
            <li><a href="indi.asp?id=13612" class="md">
              <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:text-top; padding:30px 10px;">Child<br>
                1.1<span>(1893 - 1919)</span></div>
              </a></li>
            <li><a href="indi.asp?id=13613" class="f">
              <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:text-top; padding:30px 10px;">Child<br>
                1.2<span>(1895 - )</span></div>
              </a>               
            </li>

          </ul>
    </li>  

    <li class="parentWithAncestor"><a href="" class="f">
      <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:central; padding:30px 10px; width:80px;">Main <br>Person<span>(1866 - )</span></div>
      </a>
    </li>    

    <li class="marriage" style="position: relative">
          <ul class="c" style="position: relative">
            <li style="position: relative"><a href="indi.asp?id=04947" class="md" style="position: relative">
              <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:text-top; padding:30px 10px; position: relative">Child<br>
                2.1<span>(1900 - 1943)</span></div>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li style="position: relative"><a href="indi.asp?id=04950" class="m" style="position: relative">
              <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:text-top; padding:30px 10px; position: relative">Child<br>
                2.2<span>(1902 - )</span></div>
              </a></li>
            <li style="position: relative"><a href="indi.asp?id=04950" class="m" style="position: relative">
              <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:text-top; padding:30px 10px; position: relative">Child<br>
                2.3<span>(1902 - )</span></div>
              </a></li>
            <li style="position: relative"><a href="indi.asp?id=04950" class="m" style="position: relative">
              <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:text-top; padding:30px 10px; position: relative">Child<br>
                2.4<span>(1902 - )</span></div>
              </a></li>
            <li style="position: relative"><a href="indi.asp?id=04950" class="m" style="position: relative">
              <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:text-top; padding:30px 10px; position: relative">Child<br>
                2.5<span>(1902 - )</span></div>
              </a></li>
            <li style="position: relative"><a href="indi.asp?id=04950" class="m" style="position: relative">
              <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:text-top; padding:30px 10px; position: relative">Child<br>
                2.6<span>(1902 - )</span></div>
              </a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent"><a href="" class="m">
      <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:central; padding:30px 10px; width:80px;">Husband<br>2<span>(1861 - 1894)</span></div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the css:

```
.tree * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {

    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666;
    background-color:#fff;

}

.tree{
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.tree ul {
    padding-top: 5px; position: relative;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size:0;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
    //float: left; 
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 70px 5px 0 5px;
    font-size: 12px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 70px;
}
.tree li::after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after {
    display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
//.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}


/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.tree li li:only-child::before {
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-right:none;
}

.tree ul.p>li::before {
    border:none;
    content: '&';
    left:0;
    width:100%; 
    }

.tree ul.p>li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: none;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}

.tree ul.p>li::after{
    border-left: none;
}

/* Use pf to indicate that its a child of another family. */
.tree ul.pf>li::before {
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-right:none;
    }

.tree ul.pf>li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: none;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}

.tree ul.pf>li::after{
    border-left: none;
}



/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul.c {
    padding-top: 70px; 
    }


.tree ul ul.c::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
    border: none;
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    background-color:#fff;
    /*background-image:url(circle.jpg)*/
    /*color: #fff;
    background-color:#999;*/
    display: inline-block;
    min-width:50px;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;


    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li a span{
    display:block;
    font-size: 10px;

    }   

.tree li a.m{width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:15px;font-size:12px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #c8e4fb; box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000}
.tree li a.f{width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:50px;font-size:12px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #ffc0cb; box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000}
.tree li a.m_dead{width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:15px;font-size:12px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #F1F9FE; box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000}
.tree li a.f_dead{width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:50px;font-size:12px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #FFF0F2;box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000}
.tree li a.m_nolink{width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:15px;font-size:12px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #c8e4fb; box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000}
.tree li a.f_nolink{width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:50px;font-size:12px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #ffc0cb; box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000}
.tree li a.m_dead_nolink{width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:15px;font-size:12px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #F1F9FE; box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000}
.tree li a.f_dead_nolink{width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:50px;font-size:12px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #FFF0F2;box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000}

.tree li.marriage{width:200px;height:1px; border: 1px; border-color: #000; color: #000; border-style: solid; padding: 0 ; background: #000; position: relative;}
.tree li.marriage::before{border: none}
.tree  ul.pf>li.parent::before{border: none}
.tree  ul.pf>li.parentWithAncestor::before{border-top: none;}



.tree li a.m:hover{width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:15px;font-size:12px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #c8e4fb; box-shadow:0 0 4px #222 inset}
.tree li a.f:hover{width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:50px;font-size:12px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #ffc0cb; box-shadow:0 0 4px #222 inset}
.tree li a.m_dead:hover{width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:15px;font-size:12px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #F1F9FE; box-shadow:0 0 4px #222 inset}
.tree li a.f_dead:hover{width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:50px;font-size:12px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #FFF0F2; box-shadow:0 0 4px #222 inset}
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you mean by you "cant get the children to be centered w.r.t. the marriage." Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Sure. I will Edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to center the child of class marriage below this element?

You have to work with position left or negative margins, because the bounds of the children, the ul element, is the element .marriage which has a smaller width.

So I don't see any other chance as use position left property or negative margins to position the element horizontally centered.

But I'm not sure if I got your question right.